# LIMIT claus when doing a load more function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so im trying to a basic load more function.

Currently, 8 results are shown on my page from the database.

As soon as the user scrolls, a load more button appears and on clicking it runs an ajax request to another php page which loads in 8 more results. This works in practice, but i cant figure out how to go about loading e,g, 8 - 16, then 16, 24 etc.

How should i got about changing my LIMIT claus to increase the number by e.g. 8 each time so that the next set of results are fetched. (Im testing it with just 1 result loaded each time so that i can see if its changing them easier.)

So here the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php',
           success: function(html) {
              var el = jQuery(html);
              jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
           }
        });
    });
});
```

And then the query for loading more:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE frontpage = 1 LIMIT 8, 1";
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Hope i have explained it enough.

Comment: Just a side-note: You should only fetch the *new* data, not all data you fetched before again, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner counter or other counter to see what page should be loaded:

```
var pageIndex = 1;
$('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
       success: function(html) {
          var el = jQuery(html);
          jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
          $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
          pageIndex++;
       }
    });
});
```

On server side create MySQL query with using `pageIndex` value:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE frontpage = 1 LIMIT 8, 8;
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE frontpage = 1 LIMIT 16, 8;
SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE frontpage = 1 LIMIT 24, 8; -- etc
```

Comment: Okay i see this one, so in the loadmorebuilds.php i would GET the pageIndex and then use that as a variable to determine the first limit value?

Comment: That's exactly what i mean)

Comment: So simple :) works spot on, just need to tweak it for when there not results etc :)

Thanks for the help!